# Is it possible to get a PR to restart the merge when the target branch has been updated in VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops

To give some context I will start with what I am trying to acheive.

I have a web service that receives data from a VSTS service hook. The service hook posts data when a PR is created or Updated and also when 'Pull request merge attempted'.

The point of my web service is to check that the source branch of the PR is up to date with the target branch.

All works fine, when the PR is created and also when the source branch changes (this equates to PR created and PR updated respectively).

However if the target branch is updated while the PR is waiting to be completed, I want my service to be posted to and this can set the PR status back to failed as the source branch is no longer up to date.

If I update the target branch, currently I can just complete the PR even though if my service had been posted to again it would have said 'no you can't complete this'. I can manually force it to post to the service again but using 'Restart Merge' on the PR but this is not ideal. The process of resarting the merge must fire the 'Pull Request Merge Attempted' event.

So What I'm wondering is if there is a way to make it automatically retry the merge when the Target branch is updated?

Any help with this (or if you have some tips about doing this whole check the source is up to date with the target) would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

[image: PR Top right menu]

Comment: Nowadays there are options in AzDev called "Semi-Linear Merge"  and "Rebase, fast-forward", both of which will ensure the branch is up to date at the time the PR is completed. So you may not need your service to force it if you use those merge strategies. **However**, note that if the source branch has new merge commits, you probably don't want to rebase, so if you lock it down for normal developers, you'll need a way to allow certain users to override that policy, if you ever do PRs with branches containing new merge commits.

Comment: This will not help you so not an answer, but this may help others getting here through Google trying to manually fix their PRs reported changes: Restart Merge and Abandon / Reactivate didn't work for me. Restart Merge would always report the PR is already up to date. What did work was changing the target branch to something else and then back. This forced the PR to recalculate the merge. Edit: I should also add that now being 2024, this is Azure DevOps now and not VSTS anymore

Answer (score 2):

For now, the PR won’t be updated automatically after new changes are pushed to target branch, unless you click restart merge for the PR manually (since there also has no such REST API to restart merge for a PR).

And the workaround is **abandon and reactive the PR** after you find the source branch is not up to date with target branch (target branch updates), then you will find the reactive PR is updated.

To abandon and reactive a PR, you can refer the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#status):

- Abandon a PR

  ```
  PATCH https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoID}/pullRequests/{PullRequestID}?api-version=3.0
  ```

  application/json

  ```
  {
    "status": "abandoned"
  }
  ```
- Reactive a PR

  ```
  PATCH https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoID}/pullRequests/{PullRequestID}?api-version=3.0
  ```

  application/json

  ```
  {
    "status": "active"
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The "restart merge" through API is possible.

If you look at what the "restart merge" button does (through dev tools network tab), it sends a PATCH request on the pull request ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 ) with the body:

```
{"mergeStatus":1}
```

Therefor as a workaround all you need is a custom task that uses System Access Token to iterate through all pull requests in a repository that is being build and make the PATCH request for all of them.

It's unfortunate, but not really too hard and if you are willing to write it in NODE, then there're NPM packages with Azure DevOps custom tasks SDK & Azure DevOps REST API, which is all you need.